# Unable to connect to [http://slavesolrdomain:port/solr], Core: [sitecore_web_index] in Master Slave Solr Configuration

Tags: solr

I am facing issue while this unconventional issue in the `Sitecore Solr Master Slave configuration`.

Below are the details.

**Sitecore Version:** Sitecore 8.2 Update 6

**Solr Version:** 6.4.0 (We are using this as previous vendor used this)

**Hosting Platform:** These all are in-premise VM's

1. I have Master Slave Configuration for Solr to be in use for Sitecore.
2. I have a Slave server pointed in CD and Master in CM.
3. Our Site is working absolutely fine.
4. But still, we are getting below error printed in Log files.

```
    
> 7860 09:46:24 Unable to connect to [http://slavesolrdomain:port/solr], Core: [sitecore_web_index] in Master Slave Solr Configuration
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: 

4040org.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionorg.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionCan not find: schema.xml [C:\solr\server\solr\sitecore_web_index\conf\schema.xml]404

> 
> Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.GetSchema()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize()
```

5. I tried to access the Slave Solr admin panel from the browser on CD VM on and it is working fine I can go to the web index also.
6. I also tried to create the item and publish it to this and it is also getting reflected.
7. Only the thing which I am doing which is against the concept is Our Slave servers are connected to Load Balancer but I am accessing these directly with IPs in the CD server.

Please let me know if require any more information.

Comment: Have you checked, if the schema.xml file is actually there on the slave? http://slavesolrdomain:port/solr/#/sitecore_web_index/files

Comment: yes it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this issue and below steps I followed to resolve it.

1. I was using NAT IP so I checked my host file for this.
2. It was host file entry where the host entry was made to another IP.
3. Then I removed all the Solr host entry for this.
4. Then I checked the issues was not getting reproduced.
5. I also changed it to come from LB and it also working fine.

So I can conclude that the issue was wrong host entry which was pointing to the Solr which was not having schema file.